# check if toggle button is checked in another activity android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have activity_A which contains the toggle button and activity_B where i want to check if those buttons are checked and do something, but i don't know how i can do this. I know how i can do this in activity A.
For example, on Actiivity_B when i click search_button i want to check if soy is checked do something.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> checkedAllergens = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> fetchedAllergens =new ArrayList<String>();
    // String fetcdedAllergens=new String();
    List<String> fetcdedAllergensList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> soy2= new ArrayList<String>();

  searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//i understand that the code must be placed in here
//public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        // if (soy.isChecked()) {
            // soy2.add("Soy");
            // soy2.add("Σόγια");
            // soy2.add("soja");
            // soy2.add("Soybeans");
            // checkedAllergens.add(soy2);
            // System.out.println(soy2);
            // System.out.println(checkedAllergens);
           // if (fetchedAllergens.contains(checkedAllergens))
               // System.out.println("not allowed");
        // }
        // else {
            // textView.setText("Soy Off");
            // soy1 = "no";                             
            });

        }
```

Comment: The most suitable way is to use `bundles` as an argument. Using bundles you can send data between activities. Another option is to use `shared preferences` as a standard way to persist data in you application.

Comment: Does activity A call B ? Then just pass a listener

Answer (score 0):

Best way to send data from one activity to another is to use `SharedPreferences`. When a toggle switch is clicked, you can assign `true` to a shared preference variable `isToggled` in your `Activity-A`

Like this:

```
Boolean isToggled = yourToggleSwitch.isChecked();

            if (isToggled) {

                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(isToggled, "true");
                editor.commit();

            }
```

Once you reach your `Activity-B`, just check in your shared preferences if the value of `isToggled` is `true` like this :

```
Boolean isToggled= sharedpreferences.getString(isToggled, "");
```

If it is `true`, you can do whatever you want.

Another way to send data from one activity to another is to use Intends and bundle. But this can be used only if you are very sure your app will go only to `Activity-B` after `Activity-A` without taking any other path.

Comment: let me check that and i'll be back.